# How to fix 'Segmentation fault (core dumped" error in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm having issues with Keras. Basically, it gives me the following error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" when I try to fit a model with a conv2d layer.

My code works on the CPU. It also works without any conv2d layers (even though it's ineffective for my use case). I've got cuda, cudnn, and tensorflow installed. I've tried reinstalling keras and tensorflow.

Code:

```
def model_build():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(input_shape = (env_size()[0], env_size()[1], 1), filters=4, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=1, activation=swisher))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=4, kernel_size=(5,5), strides=1, activation=swisher))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=4, kernel_size=(5,5), strides=1, activation=swisher))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=4, kernel_size=(5,5), strides=1, activation=swisher))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='softmax'))
    model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
    return model

if __name__ == '__main__':
    y = model_build()
    y.compile(loss = "mean_squared_error", optimizer = 'adam')
    y.fit(x=env(), y = np.array([[0,0,0,0]])
```

Error:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Epoch 1/1
2019-03-27 05:52:27.687323: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2019-03-27 05:52:27.789975: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:964] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-03-27 05:52:27.790819: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1411] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce RTX 2060 major: 7 minor: 5 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.83
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 5.73GiB freeMemory: 5.40GiB
2019-03-27 05:52:27.790834: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1490] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-03-27 05:52:28.068080: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:971] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-03-27 05:52:28.068115: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:977]      0
2019-03-27 05:52:28.068121: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:990] 0:   N
2019-03-27 05:52:28.068487: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1103] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 5147 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 2060, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
2019-03-27 05:52:28.177752: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:113] Allocation of 518619136 exceeds 10% of system memory.
2019-03-27 05:52:28.337277: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:113] Allocation of 518619136 exceeds 10% of system memory.
2019-03-27 05:52:28.500486: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:113] Allocation of 518619136 exceeds 10% of system memory.
2019-03-27 05:52:28.586280: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:113] Allocation of 518619136 exceeds 10% of system memory.
2019-03-27 05:52:28.675738: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:113] Allocation of 518619136 exceeds 10% of system memory.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

EDIT:

Self-contained example.

```
import numpy as np
import keras

model = keras.models.Sequential() #Sequential model type.
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=(3,3), strides = 1, activation="sigmoid")) #Convolutional layer.
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten()) #Flatten layer.
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(4)) #Dense layer of 4 units.
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam') #compile model.
y = np.random.rand(1,4) #Random expected output
x = np.random.rand(1, 38, 21, 1) # Random input.
model.fit(x, y) #And fit...
```

EDIT2:

Keras version: 'v2.1.6-tf'

Tensorflow-GPU version: 'v1.12'

Python version: 'v3.5.2'

CUDA version: 'v9.0.176'

CUDNN version: 'v7.2.1.38-1+cuda9.0

Ubuntu version: 'v16.04'

Comment: What is `env()` returning.? What is the size of it in memory.?

Comment: @SreeramTP I have edited my post with the code for env() and a related function...

Comment: Your images are just too big, you should downscale them to something like 320x180 or similar size, and it might start working.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro, tried it all the way to 96 by 54 and it still gives a segfault error.

Comment: Then maybe the problem is somewhere in your code (which we haven't seen) and it is not related to TensorFlow going out of memory at all

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro, ok, which part of the code do you need to see?

Comment: A self-containing example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro, self-contained example in edit I just made.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro, could this problem be due to my GPU possibly not having been installed correctly?

Comment: You mean GPU drivers and/or software? Possibly, I cannot reproduce the issue with your code.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro, well, I just reinstalled CUDA, same error... I'll try to reinstall the graphics drivers, I guess.

Comment: Could you add to your question what versions you are using for python, keras, tensorflow-gpu, cuda and cudnn?

Comment: @Spen, it's now in the edit. Let me know if you need anything else...

Comment: Your MWE works fine (if in addition `, input_shape=(38, 21, 1)` is added to the first conv layer). That means it must be something related to your system or installation. Your python, tensorflow and cuda version should be compatible. For cudnn I definitely would use a `7.0.x` version instead of the `7.2` version since that is officially compatible with tf `1.12`. I'm not sure about the keras version.

Comment: @Spen, thank you so much. I just had to downgrade cuDNN to v7.1.21. Issue solved. Do you mind writing an answer so I can mark this as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MWE works fine for me (if I add `, input_shape=(38, 21, 1)` to the first convolution layer):

```
import numpy as np
import keras

model = keras.models.Sequential() #Sequential model type.
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=(3,3), strides = 1, activation="sigmoid", input_shape=(38, 21, 1))) #Convolutional layer.
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten()) #Flatten layer.
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(4)) #Dense layer of 4 units.
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam') #compile model.
y = np.random.rand(2, 4) #Random expected output
x = np.random.rand(2, 38, 21, 1) # Random input.
model.fit(x, y)
```

That means that your issue must come from your system or installation.

Looking at the [compatibility chart of tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#tested_build_configurations) shows that your python, tensorflow and CUDA versions should be compatible.

For your configuration the cuDNN version `7.0.x` is recommended.
The cuDNN version `7.2` that you are using is probably incompatible.
Try installing / using cuDNN `7.0.x`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your GPU does not have enough memory. Your model does not seem to be too big, so I would guess that the problem comes from the line:

```
y.fit(x=env(), y = np.array([[0,0,0,0]])
```

The output of `env()` might be too big to be handle by your GPU memory.

Comment: Oh ok. Is there any way I can sort-of "chop it up" and feed the array in batches?

Comment: Absolutely. You can use minibatch generated by a "generator". Keras for instance comes with an [image generator](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/)

Comment: thanks but the same error is still occuring, no matter the batch size.

Comment: also had the same issue due to not enough RAM. Are you loading a lot of data?